# How do I print the content of a TextArea?

Tags: javafx, printing, textarea

So currently I'm trying to make a print feature for my Notepad application. I already have a kind of working Print feature, but it prints the full TextArea not only the string that is written into it.

I already tried to make it just print a string, but the PrintJob is not able to handle it, because it needs the actual TextArea, where the Text is written into.

My current Print Stuff:

```
public void doPrint() {
        String toPrint = writeArea.getText();
        printSetup(writeArea, Main.primaryStage);
    }

    private final Label jobStatus = new Label();

    private void printSetup(Node node, Stage owner)
    {
        // Create the PrinterJob
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        if (job == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Show the print setup dialog
        boolean proceed = job.showPrintDialog(owner);

        if (proceed)
        {
            print(job, node);
        }
    }

    private void print(PrinterJob job, Node node)
    {
        // Set the Job Status Message
        jobStatus.textProperty().bind(job.jobStatusProperty().asString());

        // Print the node
        boolean printed = job.printPage(node);

        if (printed)
        {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
```

What I want to have:
A print that only shows the String, just like any other notepad application does if you try to print something

What I currently get:
The full textarea with frame.

Comment: You can wrap the text of the TextArea to a Text and print it. like: `printSetup(new Text(writeArea), Main.primaryStage);` One problem that I've noticed, that the first line isn't visible, and IDK why. Maybe you can also experiment and find out why.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that idea. But somehow I can't apply that `new Text` to my write area... Am I just retarded or does it not work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment you can wrap it into a Text, but then the first line for some reason isn't displayed correctly.

The solution would be to use a Label instead like:

`printSetup(new Label(toPrint), Main.primaryStage);`

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your help! It actually worked, kinda at least. I had to tweak it a little bit further, but here's the solution I used:
```String toPrint = writeArea.getText(); printSetup(new Label(toPrint), Main.primaryStage); ``` It's janky af, but it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't see any difference, but I`m glad I could help you ;)